# Inserir num array entre determinados valores

Tags: lua, time, lua-table

Tenho dois valores no formato de hora, `20:03:02` e `20:03:35`, que estão num *array* em Lua.

```
hora_array={"20:03:02", "20:03:35"}
```

A diferença entre os dois valores é de 33 segundos (20:03:02 - 20:03:35 = 33).

Quero inserir nesse mesmo *array* os valores de um em um segundo, ou seja 20:03:03, 20:03:04 até chegar ao valor 20:03:35 (+ 33 elementos no *array*).

Como posso somar um número a uma *string*? O resultado final do *array* seria este:

```
hora_array={"20:03:02","20:03:03","20:03:04","..." "20:03:35"}
```

Comment: Você poderia reformular a pergunta?

Comment: Queria so adicionar no array, entre o primeiro elemento e o segundo elemento todos os valores ate chegar ao 20:03:35. Ou seja somar sempre mais um, e inserir no array.

Comment: ok, vamos lá!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma ou se está totalmente livre de problemas mas acho que é isto que precisa:

```
function str2time(hora) 
    return tonumber(string.sub(hora, 1, 2)) * 3600 + tonumber(string.sub(hora, 4, 5)) * 60 + tonumber(string.sub(hora, 7, 8))
end

hora_array = {"20:03:02", "20:03:35"}
horaInicial = str2time(hora_array[1])
horaFinal = str2time(hora_array[2])
hora_array = {}
for i = horaInicial, horaFinal do
    hora = math.floor(i / 3600)
    minuto = math.floor((i - hora * 3600) / 60)
    segundo =  math.floor(i - hora * 3600 - minuto * 60)
    table.insert(hora_array, string.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hora, minuto, segundo))
end

for i, v in ipairs(hora_array) do print(v) end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/t0ljH9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/InsertInArray). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/InsertInArray.lua).

Comment: em quantas linguagens você programa, *meu filho*? :P

Comment: Eu sei programar, a linguagem não importa muito. Quando é só uma questão de algoritmo mesmo que eu não saiba uma linguagem é só dar uma olhada na documentação. Quando é problema específico da linguagem, das tecnologias que ela costuma usar aí eu só consigo fazer no que eu trabalho ou já trabalhei. Linguagem não importa. Fazendo uma analogia, eu sei dirigir carros, pode ser qualquer marca e modelo. O que importa é saber dirigir.