# Calcular de x em x segundos

Tags: lua, time

Tenho este código que calcula em 1 segundo em 1 segundo entre uma certa hora para depois inserir numa tabela. Em vez de calcular a cada 1 segundo, como posso calcular, por exemplo, de 5 em 5 segundos?

```
for y = horaInicial, horaFinal-1 do
    hora = tostring(math.floor(y / (3600)))
    minuto = tostring(math.floor((y - hora * (3600)) / (60)))
    segundo =  tostring(math.floor(y - hora * (3600) - minuto * (60)))

end
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que é esse "calcular em 5 segundos".

Comment: Esse codigo insere numa tabela de 1 em 1 segundo, entre a hora inicial e a hora final. Queria que calculasse com um determinado secundo, como por exemplo 5.

Comment: Topico com o codigo completo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49812/inserir-num-array-entre-determinados-valores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta adicionar um terceiro parâmetro para o [`for`](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) indicado os pulos que devem ser dados. Assim:

```
function str2time(hora) 
    return tonumber(string.sub(hora, 1, 2)) * 3600 + tonumber(string.sub(hora, 4, 5)) * 60 + tonumber(string.sub(hora, 7, 8))
end

hora_array = {"20:03:02", "20:03:35"}
horaInicial = str2time(hora_array[1])
horaFinal = str2time(hora_array[2])
hora_array = {}
for i = horaInicial, horaFinal - 1, 5 do --note o 5 aqui --------------------------
    hora = math.floor(i / 3600)
    minuto = math.floor((i - hora * 3600) / 60)
    segundo =  math.floor(i - hora * 3600 - minuto * 60)
    table.insert(hora_array, string.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hora, minuto, segundo))
end

for i, v in ipairs(hora_array) do print(v) end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/I45bbW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CalcHour). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/CalcHour.lua).